# Debugging network applications and testing for synchronicity?

Tags: c++, debugging, sockets, networking, synchronization

If I have a server running on my machine, and several clients running on other networks, what are some concepts of testing for synchronicity between them? How would I know when a client goes out-of-sync?
I'm particularly interested in how network programmers in the field of game design do this (or just any *continuous* network exchange application), where realtime synchronicity would be a commonly vital aspect of success.
I can see how this may be easily achieved on LAN via side-by-side comparisons on separate machines... but once you branch out the scenario to include clients from foreign networks, I'm just not sure how it can be done without clogging up your messaging system with debug information, and therefore effectively changing the way that synchronicity would result *without* that debug info being passed over the network.
So what are some ways that people get around this issue?
For example, do they simply induce/simulate latency on the local network before launching to foreign networks, and then hope for the best? I'm hoping there are some more concrete solutions, but this is what I'm doing in the meantime...

Answer (score 1):

When you say synchronized, I believe you are talking about network latency. Meaning, that a client on a local network may get its gaming information sooner than a client on the other side of the country. Correct? 
If so, then I'm sure you can look for books or papers that cover this kind of topic, but I can give you at least one way to detect this latency and provide a way to manage it.

To detect latency, your server can use a type of trace route program to determine how long it takes for data to reach each client. A common Linux program example can be found here http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_traceroute.htm. While the server is handling client data, it can also continuously collect the latency statistics and provide the data to the clients. For example, the server can update each client on its own network latency and what the longest latency is for the group of clients that are playing each other in a game.

The clients can then use the latency differences to determine when they should process the data they receive from the server. For example, a client is told by the server that its network latency is 50 milliseconds and the maximum latency for its group it 300 milliseconds. The client then knows to wait 250 milliseconds before processing game data from the server. That way, each client processes game data from the server at approximately the same time.

There are many other (and probably better) ways to handle this situation, but that should get you started in the right direction.